# how to check and download corrupted pdf files using coldfusion?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

```html
<cfif isPDFFile("book.pdf")>
Not corrupted!<br/>
<cfelse>
Corrupted pdf file!
</cfif>
```

I'm new to coldfusion. Can anybody help me how to check and download corrupted pdf files using coldfusion.

if book.pdf is corrupted one then isPDFFile() returns false (i.e this function returns that book.pdf is not a pdf file). So,can we use this point for checking if a pdf file is corrupted or not?

Is this the right way to do? If not,what's the right way and how to download those corrupted pdf files?

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion's `isPDFfile` function already returns if the file is invalid or corrupt. But you may want to distinguish between the cause of the return value:

```
<cfset pdfFileLocation = "book.pdf">

<cfif (not isSimpleValue(pdfFileLocation)) or (not len(pdfFileLocation))>
    <cfoutput>File's location is invalid.</cfoutput>
<cfelseif not fileExists(pdfFileLocation)>
    <cfoutput>File not found on location #htmlEditFormat(pdfFileLocation)#.</cfoutput>
<cfelseif not isPDFfile(pdfFileLocation)>
    <cfoutput>File is either not a PDF document or its content is damaged.</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>File is a valid PDF document.</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

What do you mean with "download"? In your example, you already have the file `book.pdf` in the current directory (relative path). If you want to repair the document, use ColdFusion's `fileReadBinary` function to inspect the binary data. [Repairing PDF isn't exactly a child's play though.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)

Comment: The first sentence of this answer appears to be missing a word.